# Fast Pandas.DataFrame multicolumn instantiation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some code which looks like:

```py
    df['MONTH'] = [df.index[i].month for i in range(len(df))]
    df['WEEK'] = [df.index[i].week for i in range(len(df))]
    df['DAY'] = [df.index[i].day for i in range(len(df))]
    df['HOUR'] = [df.index[i].hour for i in range(len(df))]
    df['MINUTE'] = [df.index[i].minute for i in range(len(df))]
```

This is quite slow, as it runs through the length of df five times.

Is there a way to do this approach in 1*N, reducing the time taken to compute this by a factor of 5?

I was thinking, something like:

```py
df[['MONTH'],['WEEK'], ...['HOUR']] = [vector assignment]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `attrgetter` from operator module:

```
import operator

attrs = ['month', 'week', 'day', 'hour', 'minute']

dft = pd.DataFrame(operator.attrgetter(*attrs)(df.index),
                   columns=df.index, index=[c.upper() for c in attrs]).T
df = pd.concat([df, dft], axis='columns')
```

```
>>> df
                            A  MONTH  WEEK  DAY  HOUR  MINUTE
2021-08-05 12:43:09  0.081188      8    31    5    12      43
2021-08-07 05:05:09  0.444124      8    31    7     5       5
2021-08-08 21:27:09  0.523709      8    31    8    21      27
2021-08-10 13:49:09  0.544349      8    32   10    13      49
```

Note the `FutureWarning`:

> :1: FutureWarning: weekofyear and week have been deprecated, please use DatetimeIndex.isocalendar().week instead, which returns a Series.  To exactly reproduce the behavior of week and weekofyear and return an Index, you may call pd.Int64Index(idx.isocalendar().week)